# Identify why CMake is re-configured every time a source file is changed

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, toolchain

I have a big project and for some reason CMake configure is being run every time a source file is changed. Is there a simple way to identify why the reconfigure was triggered?

The command that make calls and does the reconfigure is the following:

```
 cmake -H/home/ME/BIG_PROJECT -B/home/ME/BIG_PROJECT/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
```

When there are no changes, that command does nothing.

Comment: Run `make -d` and see why make is deciding to re-build the cmake files.

Comment: on start, make calls that cmake command I listed above (it is on one of the first targets). And that cmake call does checks and reconfigures the project.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Are you using the makefiles generated by cmake and that is re-running cmake?  Or are you running your own makefile, that has a rule that invokes cmake?

Comment: CMake automatically adds a "check" target that does that.

Comment: OK.  So if you run `make -d` as I suggested in the first comment, it will tell you why make decides that it needs to re-run cmake.  It will print a ton of output, so you want to redirect it to a file, but look for the invocation of the cmake and backtract from there and it will say which files were deemed to be "newer"; these are the files make used to decide that it needed to re-run this recipe and invoke cmake.